# Will JavaScript/userscript in Tamper Monkey apply to ajax updating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm planning to create a userscript for twitch.tv that will hide streams with titles matching my blacklist. For example, streams that have Russian usually have '[RUS]' in their title. Therefore, I can add that to my blacklist and hide them when they are loaded. However, I am unsure if the javascript will continue applying to the extra content that is added to the page when scrolling down. To see this updating in action, please go to http://www.twitch.tv/directory/all and scroll down the page.

Thanks

Comment: what javascript? You haven't shown a single line of code?

Comment: I am still planning it but I am just asking for a general interaction in this case.

Comment: Well start by writing the code and trying it and come back when you have problems with real code and you will get plenty of help then

Answer (score -1):

Before you start writing the code you should first have a clear idea of what you want and how you want it. Never go into it with a blank canvas and no visual idea of what you want. Visualize the code before the coding began.